# EF6 Child and Grandchild entities pointing to the same parent

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have the following entities

```
Address {
  Id,
  Data
}

Location {
  Id,
  AddressId,
  Data
}

Contact {
  Id,
  LocationId,
  AddressId,
  Data
}
```

When I create a Location object I populate the Address as well.  I also capture data for a contact, and for this instance I need it to point to the same address object.

If this is all a new object graph, will calling save will reuse the Address object or will a new one be created?

If a new one is created, is there a way to make it so that the same Address object is used for both Location and Contact?

Thank you,

Comment: The `AddressId` in `Contact` is redundant, because `LocationId` points to unique `Location` which in turn has unique `Address`. Speaking with navigation properties, you have `Contact.Location.Address`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.. The idea is that the Contact might have a different address than the location but they might be same at the same time.